# How to "anchor" the horizontal scrollbar to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have an element with lots of content that has a horizontal scrollbar. However, the scrollbar is always "attached" to the left. Seems the browsers default. But since the content is aligned to the right hand side, I'm also trying to have the scrollbar to the right, both initially and during resizing.

I don't want to add any kind of `scrollLeft = scrollWidth` JavaScript as it's laggy and needs to be called on many occasions (e.g. during resize, after appending of new elements, and so on...)

I prefer a simple CSS solution, such as `direction: rtl;`, which actually makes the scrollbar behave like I desire, but it also messes up the rest of the content (because, of course, the browsers reverses everything, like the lists order, and seems to remove styles like `padding-left`).

Here's a `<p>` whose scrollbar I'd like to have "magnetized" to the right instead of to the left.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding-left: 100px;
  
  /* Seems to work but messes up the page, like where's the padding-left gone? */
  /* direction: rtl; */
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li>Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
    <li>Ten</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add text wrapper that would reset text direction back to `ltr`

```css
p {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: rtl;
}

p span {
  direction: ltr;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 50vw;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text</span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks I've tried that before but Firefox seems too clever for that and it also reverses the scroll effect again.

Comment: @kraftwer1 What you mean by that?

Comment: See here https://jsfiddle.net/sjo8karw/
(Sorry my example wasn't very accurate because in reality I'm using a <ul>).